# passing a query result received from a controler in blade, back to another controller in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I have a view that received a query result $necps from a controller, and I want to send to another controler with a form like below.
I am using a foreach to create the hidden inputs, but in the controller I get just the last record.

First question is : can I do that in a more elegant way? Sendind the entire query result at once?
Second : If not, how can I send all the array using foreach?

No Js please. Thanks a lot.

@if (isset($necps))

```
    <div style="float:left; margin-left:20px;"  >
    <form style="display:inline;" action="{{route('mostra_varios_parts')}}" method="post">
      @csrf 
      
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-mapa bi-globe texto_p"> Mapa</button> 
      @foreach($necps as $necp)  
           <input value="{{$necp->id_part}}" name="parts[id]" type="hidden">
           <input value="{{$necp->latitude}}" name="parts[latitude]" type="hidden">
           <input value="{{$necp->longitude}}" name="parts[longitude]" type="hidden">
           <input value="{{$necp->nome_part}}" name="parts[nome_part]" type="hidden">
           <input value="{{$necp->endereco}}" name="parts[endereco]" type="hidden">
      @endforeach
      
    </form>
  </div>  

  <br>
  <br>

<table class="table table-sm tabela-necessidade">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="texto_p">Nome</th>
        <th scope="col" class="texto_p">Necessidade</th>
        <th scope="col" class="texto_p">Categoria</th>
        <th scope="col" class="texto_p">Data</th>
        <th scope="col" class="texto_p">Quant</th>
        <th scope="col" class="texto_p">Unidade</th>
        <th scope="col" class="texto_p">Local</th>
        <th scope="col" class="texto_p">Observações</th>
        <!--<th scope="col" class="texto_p">Distância/Kms</th>-->
        <th class="texto_p" colspan="1">Ações</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      @if (count($necps)>0)

          @foreach($necps as $necp)
            <div>
              <tr>
                <td class="texto_p">{{$necp->nome_part}}</td>
                <td class="texto_p">{{$necp->desc_nec}}</td>
                <td class="texto_p">{{$necp->desc_cat}}</td>
                <td class="texto_p">{{$necp->data}}</td>
                <td class="texto_p">{{$necp->quant}}</td>
                <td class="texto_p">{{$necp->desc_unid}}</td>
                <td class="texto_p">{{$necp->endereco}} - {{$necp->cidade}}</td>
                <td class="texto_p">{{$necp->obs}}</td>
                <!--<td class="texto_p">{{$necp->distancia}}</td>-->
                <td>
                  <form action="" method="post">
                        @csrf 
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-conectar bi-arrow-repeat texto_p"> Conectar</button>   
                        <input value="{{$part->id}}" name="id_part_t" type="hidden">
                        <input value="{{$necp->id_nec_part}}" name="id_nec_part_t" type="hidden">
                  </form>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </div> 
            
          @endforeach

      @else
          <td><td>Nenhum registro encontrado</td></td>    
      @endif 

    </tbody>
  </table>

@endif
```

Comment: Your inputs all have the same name attribute.  `name="parts[id][]"` would post an array for each field. (change all inputs)

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute for your hidden inputs need to be unique. you can post the fields as an array like so:

```
@foreach($necps as $necp)  
  <input value="{{$necp->id_part}}" name="parts[{{ $loop->index }}][id]" type="hidden">
  <input value="{{$necp->latitude}}" name="parts[{{ $loop->index }}][latitude]" type="hidden">
  <input value="{{$necp->longitude}}" name="parts[{{ $loop->index }}][longitude]" type="hidden">
  <input value="{{$necp->nome_part}}" name="parts[{{ $loop->index }}][nome_part]" type="hidden">
  <input value="{{$necp->endereco}}" name="parts[{{ $loop->index }}][endereco]" type="hidden">
@endforeach
```

with `$loop->index` as array key you post 1 array for every `$necp`

Comment: worked very well! thanks!
But now I have an array like that :

array:2 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => "14"
    "latitude" => "-22.8104286"
    "longitude" => "-45.1904259"
    "nome_part" => "Jonh Cool"
    "endereco" => "Collins Av."
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => "24"
    "latitude" => "-22.8104286"
    "longitude" => "-42.1904259"
    "nome_part" => "Amanda Pereira"
    "endereco" => "Street ABC"
  ]
]

I need now to do another foreach in my "mapsController" , and need to access parts->latitude but laravel do not recognize the field like that.

Comment: You can just foreach that array in your controller. it is an array, so you access the values using `$part['latitude']` ( `foreach($request->get('parts') as $part)` )